# Using an AWK script in a windows program

Tags: windows, awk, translate, equation-solving

I've been struggling for days with an AWK script that solves this [Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVf71.png)

I can't seem to run AWK with any program I download for windows, so I was wondering how I can run AWK in a windows program like Visual Studio Code or if I can translate the AWK script into literally any other language that works for windows.

Comment: GNU `awk` can be compiled for Windows, and there's also a binary release. See [installation for MS Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/PC-Installation.html). I also like [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) package manager, which has [GNU awk 5.1](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/gawk). Once Chocolatey is installed, `choco install awk` (in PowerShell or command prompt (`cmd.exe`)) to install awk. Once you have awk, you can run an awk script in PowerShell or command prompt with `awk -f myscript.awk`. There's also WSL and cygwin to get Unix utilities.

Answer (score 0):

*if I can translate the AWK script into literally any other language that works for windows.*

What you describe above is done by tools called [*transpilers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpiler). My cursory search revelead existence of [AWK to go](https://benhoyt.com/writings/awkgo/) and [AWK to C](https://github.com/noyesno/awka) transpilers. Naturally before trying to use either make sure you can use `go` or `C` in your `windows`.